# Change Order of Sections Using Custom Fields

Tags: custom-field

Is there a way that I can change the order of sections using custom fields?

For example I have:

```
<section id="1"></section>
<section id="2"></section>
<section id="3"></section>
<section id="4"></section>
```

And maybe the marketing team would like to try displaying section 4 first.

I do use custom fields a lot to decide whether to display something...but changing the order I cannot think of a way to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are sections in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Have 5 custom fields:
the first 4 are your sections and the last would be your order identifier.

**CASE 1**

If you want to have the order simply revsered have the last field be a dropdown with "normal" or "reversed". (You could even say "random"... the world is your oyster)

```
$s1 = '<section id="1">$customfield1</section>';
$s2 = '<section id="2">$customfield2</section>';
$s3 = '<section id="3">$customfield3</section>';
$s4 = '<section id="4">$customfield4</section>';
if ($customfieldorder == 'reversed') {
echo $s4.$s3.$s2.$s1;
}else{ 
echo $s1.$s2.$s3.$s4;
}
```

**CASE 2**

With these 4 fields, they could simply put the info that they want to appear first in the first field and next information in the next field etc.  Then your code would be simply: (users would choose order to display simply by where they put the information.

```
$s1 = '<section id="1">$customfield1</section>';
$s2 = '<section id="2">$customfield2</section>';
$s3 = '<section id="3">$customfield3</section>';
$s4 = '<section id="4">$customfield4</section>';

echo $s1.$s2.$s3.$s4;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I was designing the page from scratch then my own answer would be to combine flexbox and custom fields.

```
<div class="flexbox">
    <section id="a" style="order: <?php echo $customfield1 ?>"></section>
    <section id="b" style="order: <?php echo $customfield2 ?>"></section>
    <section id="c" style="order: <?php echo $customfield3 ?>"></section>
    <section id="d" style="order: <?php echo $customfield4 ?>"></section>
</div>

.flexbox {
display: flex;
}
```